# Android - How do Resource resolution impacts build performance?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-resources

I participate in a project which has some resources such as :

```
<!-- Spacing -->
<dimen name="spacing_1">4dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_2">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_3">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_4">32dp</dimen>
<dimen name="spacing_5">45dp</dimen>
```

How much will build time be impacted by resource resolution so that ALL my views can have:

```
    <LinearLayout 
    ...
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_2" />
```

in every file vs simply:

```
    <LinearLayout 
    ...
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample project with 800 xmls referencing arount 25 `dimens` resolutions each.

It seems that there is no impact at all or if any it should be very small.

**Build times**

```
Original project (1 layout)  - 10 secs
800 layouts without using dimens (assigning dp directly)   - 14 secs
800 layouts using dimens references  - 14 secs
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure, but I would guess, that the resources are only accessed one time and then cached for future use.

Even if this is not the case, the impact won't be noticable unless you have like a million views.

In the official Android developer tutorials you learn, that you should create resources instead of direct assign.(There is nothing mentioned in terms of building time, they rather focus on the benefit, that you can change whole views much easier when you only need to change a resource instead of every view.)